# Using Visual Basic to pull data from within a range to use in an Excel function

Tags: excel, vba, function

Let's say that I have a three column table/range for all of 2022: date, Day of Week, and Sales. I want to be able to calculate the average sales for a Monday, Tuesday, etc. Using Visual Basic, how would I pull sales for every Monday in 2022 into the Average() function?

[image: Table Example]

Comment: use AVERAGEIFS instead on the full range.

Answer (score 0):

As Scott mentioned, Averageif, or Averageifs to test multiple criteria.

Example of Averageif for only DoW:
`=AVERAGEIF(B:B,E2,C:C)`
[image]

Example of Averageifs for Dow and Year
`=AVERAGEIFS(D:D,B:B,G2,C:C,F2)`
[image]

---

**Other** options include pivot table

This is just a quick one:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Playing With Dates (Excel Formula)

- If you have Microsoft 365, in cell `F2` you could use:

  ```
  =LET(MyArr,(TEXT($A$2:$A$33,"dddd")=$E2)*(YEAR($A$2:$A$33)=F$1)*$C$2:$C$33,
      AVERAGE(FILTER(MyArr,MyArr<>0)))
  ```

  or

  ```
  =AVERAGE(FILTER($C$2:$C$33,
      MAP(TEXT($A$2:$A$33,"dddd"),YEAR($A$2:$A$33),
          LAMBDA(lDay,lYear,AND(lDay=$E2,lYear=F$1)))))
  ```

  and copy to the right and down (`F2:G8`).
- The days are in `E2:E8` and the years e.g. `2021` and `2022`, are in `F1:G1`.
- These only use the `Date` and `Sales` columns.